# is it permissible to make 3d character for a game?

Tags: halal-haram

i want to make 3d character but i will just make the clothes such as shoes, helmet, shirt, jeans, and gloves. No human body or anything i will be making in the character creation and i will be also animating it.So, is this permissible ?

Answer (score -1):

Creating, or drawing a person, or animal can be halal. Some scholars say that drawing anything, or taking a picture of something is haram completely. There are Muslims scholars that say that you must draw a person completely in order for it to be haram like leaving out facial features such as eyes. From what I know, I don't think there is a problem here considering your intention.

Comment: As this topic in general is discussed broadly, also on this site, it would be more helpful if you could cite to support your answer, which in this case would probably be a fatwa.